# pdfcrowd converter convert php file into blank pdf

Tags: php, pdf-generation

I am using pdfcrowd to convert php file into pdf but it converts blank pdf. What may be the issue? Do pdfcrowd convert php file?

Code is here

```
<?php
    require 'pdfcrowd.php';

try
{   

    $client = new Pdfcrowd("nabinashahi", "2ef55554fe4c2d23b52b8e080cac867g");// create an API client instance


    // $pdf = $client->convertURI('http://www.google.com/');
    $pdf = $client->convertFile("C:/xampp/htdocs/pdf/page.php");// convert a web page and store the generated PDF into a $pdf variable

    // set HTTP response headers
    header("Content-Type: application/pdf");
    header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
    header("Accept-Ranges: none");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"google_com.pdf\"");


    echo $pdf;// send the generated PDF 
}
catch(PdfcrowdException $why)
{
    echo "Pdfcrowd Error: " . $why;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is that you are not converting the output generated by your php file, but the actual php file itself. pdfCrowd is able to convert HTML into pdf - I don't think they handle php source code that well, and I don't think thats what you want to do :-)